# C# Replace Characters in String with Escaped Version

Tags: c#, .net

I know the internet is loaded with information on escape characters, but I am not finding specifically what I need.  I am querying inventory information from a database and the inventory descriptions can contain a wide variety of "dangerous" characters that need escaping.  While I'm looping through my data reader, I need to replace all instances of any potential problem characters with the escaped version of that character.  I've looked at Regex.Escape, but it leaves out a few key characters such as quotation marks.  There is also Regex.Replace, but how do I tell it what the replace string should be if I the character it is replacing could be any number of things?  How would I handle the following:

SQL Query returns the following result set for inventory descriptions:

- 3/4" Wire
- 5' Rope @StoreX
- 1 1\4" Hex Nut

**I recognize there are deeper issues with the descriptions themselves, but assuming this is the data I have to work with...

```
SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader()
while(dr.Read())
 {
    string partDescription = dr["Description"].ToString();  //Here is where I need to escape any characters posing a potential issue
 }
```

Comment: Where do you want to *use* those escaped characters? What chars need escaping and the type of escaping depends on where you want to use it!

Comment: Why do you need to escape them coming out of SQL Server?  You need to escape what's going INTO SQL Server to make sure those characters don't change the semantics of an UPDATE query; but, coming out of SQL Server doesn't have that effect.  So, I'm not clear why you want to escape here...

Comment: Perhaps I'm just misinterpreting an error message then.  The data is being output on a web service in a generic list.  When I try to invoke the web service, I get "error on line 58273 at column 48: xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar"

Comment: @PeterRitchie - don't escape text going into the database (use parameters). What if you HTML-escape it now but later want to display it in plain text (CSV export) - then you will need to unescape those escapings! Better to escape just before you display/output, then you will know what escaping you need.

Comment: @Hans, yes; that's one way of dealing with *that* reason to need to escape.  The OP hasn't show *why* they need to escape.  Do they need to escape for the DB, do they need to HTML escape, do they need to URL escape, etc...

Comment: Hmmm.  Not sure why the downvote.  I explained several hours ago that the information is being output from a webservice and when I try to invoke it I get the message about an invalid xmlChar.  But I've tried a few things and can consume it in my application with no issue which is the important thing.  Josh and @Hans have both provided good info which I'm sure I will use.  But I can only accept one.  Thank you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know about the [Web Protection Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) (formerly known as AntiXSS)? That contains a lot of escapings (HTML, Javascript, XML).

Answer (score 1):

If this is for display purposes only (on the web), then you simply need to Html Encode the values before displaying them. You can do this with the HttpUtility

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("<script>alert('yo');</script>");
```